# pipe + one digit number does not echo

Tags: batch

I have a script that reads the row count of file and sets this number in variable `ROWCOUNT`.

So to add footer like this "F|5" to file file.txt with `ROWCOUNT` minus header I do the subtraction and with echo send it to file, but in that line I am not sure which part fails as "^|" should print pipe yet in screen it shows F| only and generated file is empty.

Also this stops being a problem when ROWCOUNT > 10

```
@echo off
set ROWCOUNT=7
set /A TT=ROWCOUNT-1
echo F^|%TT%>>C:\Users\file.txt
pause
```

Even with echo off this is the graphical output and file.txt is empty:

```
F|
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number immediately before redirection represents a file handle. When you use redirection like `>>someFile`, it really means `1>>someFile`, where 1 represents stdout. There is also 2 for stderr, and 0 for stdin. Other files handles can by defined by your code.

Your code has a number before the redirection, so it is being interpreted as an undefined file handle.

The solution is to simply move the redirection to the front.

```
>>C:\Users\file.txt echo F^|%TT%
```

Another option is to use parentheses

```
(echo F^|%TT%)>>C:\Users\file.txt
```

Comment: Second option (echo F^|%TT%) puts also the parentheses in file, but the first worked like a charm! Thanks for help!

Comment: @bot20141209 - The second option should not put parentheses in the output if it is typed exactly as I have shown, unless your TT value contains `)`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. previously I had written echo (F^|%TT%), so that is why parentheses were printed.